# Get ID from another table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to add a product to my DB, I need to get the category ID from another table, however i am not sure how i can do this?

Basically, i have a table with all my different categories in, and i need to pass over the text from my external web service, which will then hit the DB and get the ID of the cat its meant to be in.

Below is the code i have:

```
using (aboDataDataContext dc = new aboDataDataContext())
{
    var match = (from t in dc.tweProducts
                 where t.sku == productSku
                 select t).FirstOrDefault();

    if (match == null)
    {
        tweProduct tprod = new tweProduct()
        {
            sku = p.productcode,
            categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(catid),
            title = p.name,
            brand = p.manufacturer,
            description = p.description,
            twePrice = p.price,
            weight = decimal.TryParse(p.size, out weight) == true ? (int?)weight : null,
            size = decimal.TryParse(p.size, out weight) == true ? (int?)weight : null,
            contry = p.country,
            region = p.region,
            vintage = int.TryParse(p.vintage, out vintage) == true ? (int?)vintage : null,
            strength = p.strength,
            bottler = p.bottler,
            age = int.TryParse(p.age, out age) == true ? (int?)age : null,
            caskType = p.casktype,
            series = p.series,
            flavour = p.flavour,
            stock = p.freestock,
            tweUpdated = false,
            stockUpdated = false,
            priceUpdated = false,
            dataUpdated = false,
            imgPublished = false,
            lastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
        };
    }
}
```

SO basically the category from the web service is passing in Category_1 (for example), I need to pass this to my DB, to get the ID for Category_1 (say its 1) then insert it into my table.

Comment: Is it LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework this LINQ to Entities? Do you have navigation Properties mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstOrDefault/First/SingleOrDefault/Single accepts a predicate:

```
categoryId = dc.Categories.Single(c => c.Name == p.category).Id;
```

Comment: is there any way to contact you, i have another question you may be able to help with :)

Comment: @thatuxguy: Feel free to post a new question, and just post a link to it here. I'll try to answer it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193165/linq-why-is-it-not-updating-please - Many thanks :)

Comment: not sure what you did with the above question. Was you revision answering the code? as a lot seemed to be removed :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx), assuming you are getting valid, not null response from your webservice.

```
         categoryId = Convert.ToInt32((from c in dc.Categories
                                 where c.Name == p.category
                                 select c.Id).FirstOrDefault()),
```

Comment: Awesome, Cheers Allieswell :D